# How to use the phrase "rule out"?

Tags: phrase-usage

> I think it would be better to rule out first whether the problem is the computer or not.

Is that a correct way to use rule out?

Comment: Yes, it means **eliminate from consideration** and it is used correctly in your example.

Comment: It depends what you want to say. This question would be better formed if you explained your intentions, and then asked if your choice of verb would be suitable.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the *rule out* being used in your example, though likely understandable in the context (and I'm not sure about your context), is a bit awkward and unclear. I'd suggest rephrasing it to either *rule out the possibility that the computer is the problem* (or *it's a computer problem* or it's the machine's fault*) or *rule out the question whether the problem is caused by the computer or not*.

Comment: @Damkerng: I think what makes OP's example "unnatural" is that you normally "rule out" a ***possibility*** (that one out of multiple alternatives applies), not a ***question*** (asking *which* alternative applies). Thus *It's better to first **establish** whether the computer is faulty or not*, or *It's better to first **rule out** the computer being faulty*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To *rule something out* means to *exclude* it, to make sure that it is not possible.

I’d say that it is used incorrectly in your example. You could say:

> We don’t know what causes the problem. I think it would be better to rule out the computer first.

Or:

> I think it would be better to rule out the possibility that the computer is the problem.

So, basically, you can *find out whether* something is true, but you don’t *rule out whether*, you *rule out something*.